# Shrinking images with Flexbox. Wrapped image expands to 100% width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I created a small sample that shows movie covers and I like the "flex: calc(...)" in action. As the browser window is reduced the size of the images are also reduced a bit. However notice when the image wraps, the wrapped image is in full width. Is it possible to make the wrapped image to be the same size as the images above it?

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.movies {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 10px 15px 0;
}

.flex-item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  body {
    background: limegreen;
  }
  
  .movies {
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .flex-item {
    margin: 0 15px 32px;
    flex: calc(50% - 30px);
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  body {
    background: lightyellow;
  }

  .movies {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .flex-item {
    margin: 0 6px 15px;
    flex: calc(33.3333% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-flex.css">
  <title>Learn Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item-1 flex-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-2 flex-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71VDlRubWtL._AC_SY741_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-3 flex-item">
        <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

I want the image with the dogs to be the same size as the ones above and leave the space on the right side empty, since there is no fourth cover. Is it possible to achieve that with flexbox?

Comment: but the image with the dogs is landscape whereas the others are all portrait - so in which dimension should it be the same or should it be squashed?

Comment: they should be portrait all. It becomes landscape only after it is wrapped. I have a feeling that flexbox is not good for what I need. I should probably use grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting the width of a flex item you can also ask that it neither shrink nor grow. e.g. in your tablet case:

```
  .flex-item {
    margin: 0 15px 32px;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
```

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.movies {
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  margin: 10px 15px 0;
}

.flex-item > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  body {
    background: limegreen;
  }
  
  .movies {
    max-width: 700px;
  }

  .flex-item {
    margin: 0 15px 32px;
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 30px);
  }
}

/* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 70em) {
  body {
    background: lightyellow;
  }

  .movies {
    max-width: 1200px;
  }

  .flex-item {
    margin: 0 6px 15px;
    flex: 0 0 calc(33.3333% - 20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="learn-flex.css">
  <title>Learn Flex</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="movies">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item-1 flex-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81PWF-yAEyL._AC_SL1100_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-2 flex-item">
        <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71VDlRubWtL._AC_SY741_.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item-3 flex-item">
        <img src="https://fanart.tv/fanart/movies/12230/movieposter/101-dalmatians-5a529ef29b36c.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I need to use CSS grid.